# Jenkins reported a SSLException: Read timed out error when installing the aws sdk plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I installed jenkins with docker.

```
docker run -u root --rm -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkinsci/blueocean
```

When I downloaded the aws plugin, it reported a java https error, as follows:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:457)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:237)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:190)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read timed out
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:138)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1386)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1354)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:948)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3454)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3447)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:81)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1283)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/aws-java-sdk/1.11.995/aws-java-sdk.hpi to /var/jenkins_home/plugins/aws-java-sdk.jpi.tmp
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1288)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/aws-java-sdk/1.11.995/aws-java-sdk.hpi (redirected to: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/jenkins/plugins/aws-java-sdk/1.11.995/aws-java-sdk.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1322)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1870)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2162)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1844)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:118)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Have friends encountered the same problem, and can you give me some help, thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure on why it is erroring like that, but I would probably try using the official Jenkins container rather than a test one. e.g. `jenkins/jenkins:lts` https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins

Answer (score 0):

https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/aws-java-sdk/1.11.995/aws-java-sdk.hpi

use this URL and download the aws-java-sdk.hpi file

copy paste that file to your Jenkins -> plugin folder and restart the Jenkins it will
automatically install.